# nodejs display username to all pages when logged in

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, middleware

I am just experiencing in node.js and feeling a bit confused. I want to display username to all pages when it is logged in. I can get user id using jsonwebtoken. I am using MySQL. Here is my route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { requireAuth, checkUser } = require('../middleware/authMiddleware');

router.get('*', checkUser);

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');    
});
```

I wrote middleware code here

```
const checkUser = (req, res, next)=>{
    const token = req.cookies.jwt;
    if(token){
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, async (err, decodedToken)=>{
            
            if(err){
                console.log(err.message);
                res.locals.user = null;
                next();
            }
            else{
                res.locals.user = WHAT SHOULD I ASSIGN HERE;
                next();
            }
            
        })
    }
    else{
        res.locals.user = null;
        next();
    }

}


module.exports = { checkUser};
```

I should assign username to res.locals.user right? How to get it?

Comment: it should be `res.locals.user = decodedToken`

Comment: Yes you right, Now i see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user details is available while creating the `jwt token` then you should assign the `decodedToken` in `res.local.user`

```
const checkUser = (req, res, next)=>{
    const token = req.cookies.jwt;
    if(token){
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, async (err, decodedToken)=>{
            
            if(err){
                console.log(err.message);
                res.locals.user = null;
                next();
            }
            else{
                res.locals.user = decodedToken;
                next();
            }
            
        })
    }
    else{
        res.locals.user = null;
        next();
    }

}


module.exports = { checkUser};
```

But while creating the token your process should be like below:

```
let userDetails = {
    id: 1,
    username: "sariful",
    email: "helloworld@website.com"
    ...
};
jwt.sign(userDetails, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function () {
   ...
});
```

In jwt, when creating the token it encrypts all the data that passed in `jwt.sign`. and when you decode the token in `jwt.verify` you get the decoded details that presents in the token.

PS:

you shouldn't use `router.get('*', checkUser);` as middleware rather you should use `app.use(checkUser)`